# <ul> Sprite Issue

Tags: css, graphics, sprite, css-sprites

I have the following code

```
<ul id ="menu">
    <%foreach (var pckg in Model)
    { %>

        <li style = "text-align:center;width:60px;" class = "top-<%=pckg.Controller.ToLower() %>"> 
            li-text
        </li>

    <%} %>

</ul>
```

and following is the sprite CSS

```
.top-pkg1{ background-position: -184px 0; width: 36px; height: 36px; } 
.top-pkg2{ background-position: -270px 0; width: 36px; height: 36px; } 
.top-pkg3{ background-position: -356px 0; width: 36px; height: 36px; } 
.top-pkg4{ background-position: -517px 0; width: 36px; height: 36px; } 
.top-pkg5{ background-position: -603px 0; width: 36px; height: 31px; } 
.top-pkg5{ background-position: -689px 0; width: 36px; height: 36px; } 
.top-pkg6{ background-position: -775px 0; width: 36px; height: 36px; } 
.top-pkg7{ background-position: -861px 0; width: 36px; height: 36px; }
```

and here is the container css

```
 #menu li
    {
         display:block;
         background: url(/Content/images/TopMenu/topmenu.png) no-repeat top left; 

    }    
    #menu li a
    {
        margin-top:35px;
        text-align:center;    
    }
```

But when i ran this code i get the first image of the sprite partially shown on all li tags Couldn't figure out the problem. I created the css from [Here](http://spritegen.website-performance.org/)
Fiddle link is 
http://jsfiddle.net/tassadaque/LnGqX/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@tassadaque; You already define background-position in your `li`  image  url `top left`

```
background: url(/Content/images/TopMenu/topmenu.png) no-repeat top left;
```

So remove `top left` position from your `li` image url and write like this:

```
background: url(/Content/images/TopMenu/topmenu.png) no-repeat;
```

**Edit**
write :

```
#menu li {background: url(/Content/images/TopMenu/topmenu.png) no-repeat;}

#menu li.top-pkg1{ background-position: -184px 0; width: 36px; height: 36px; }
#menu li.top-pkg2{ background-position: -270px 0; width: 36px; height: 36px; }
#menu li.top-pkg3{ background-position: -356px 0; width: 36px; height: 36px; }
#menu li.top-pkg4{ background-position: -20px 0; width: 36px; height: 36px; }
#menu li.top-pkg5{ background-position: -603px 0; width: 36px; height: 31px; }
#menu li.top-pkg5{ background-position: -689px 0; width: 36px; height: 36px; }
#menu li.top-pkg6{ background-position: -775px 0; width: 36px; height: 36px; }
#menu li.top-pkg7{ background-position: -861px 0; width: 36px; height: 36px; }
```

Comment: Because the id selector is more specific than the class selector btw.

Answer (score 0):

First, run:

```
<ul id ="menu">
    <%foreach (var pckg in Model)
    { %>

        <li style = "text-align:center;width:60px;"> 
            top-<%=pckg.Controller.ToLower() %>
        </li>

    <%} %>

</ul>
```

To see if you get top-pkg1, top-pkg2, etc.
It seems to me that you have the same class in all li's.

Comment: Already done that. Class names are correctly generated and classes are properly applied

Comment: Try to rename .top-pkg1{ background-position: -184px 0; width: 36px; height: 36px; } to #menu li.top-pkg1{ background-position: -184px 0; width: 36px; height: 36px; } , any changes?